# compute angle of rotation between two orthographic projections

Tags: math, graphics, rotation, unity-game-engine, game-engine

[image: Orthographic projection 1]

[image: Orthographic projection 2]

I Have the orthographic projection of a unit cube with one of its vertex at origin as shown above. I have the x,y (no z) co ordinates of the projections. I would like to compute the angle of rotation of the plane to get the second orthographic projection from the first one (maybe euler angles??)

Is there any other easy way to compute this?

**UPDATE:**

[image: Rotation Matrix]

Could I use this rotation matrix to get a system of equations in cos, sin angles and the x,y and x',y' and solve them easily? Or is there any easier way to get the angles back? (Am I on the right direction to solve this? )

Comment: So you know the result of the projection but not its parameters – right? Is the second transformation only a rotation or can it include translation and scaling?

Comment: @Chronial no translation but maybe scaling but for simplicity we can keep the scaling to maybe some constant say 1

Comment: I don’t know of a simple solution to this problem. I guess you need to use the points you can see with an unknown z coordinate and solve an equation system for an unknown transformation matrix.

Comment: @Chronial Could you please help me form a system of equations or some math form to start with. I tried but couldn't get anywhere. I could how you where I got to with it. Since its a unit cube I assumed this would be easy but its apparently not

Comment: @Chronial could you check my update and let me know if I am on the right path atleast?

Comment: I think there might be another way, but I have one more question: your question states that one of the cube corners is in origin, but in your images the cube center is in origin – which one is it?

Comment: I was just trying some stuff and grabbed the pictures then. It actually doesnt matter I can translate them. you can use which ever is easy for computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First method

Use this idea to generate equations:

[image]

a1, a2 and a3 are coordinates in the original system, x y are the coordinates you get from the end-result and z is a coordinate you don’t know. This generates 2 equations for every point of the cube. E.g for point 0 with coordinates (-1, -1, 1) these are:

[image]

Do this for the 4 front points of the cube and you get 8 equations. Now add the fact that this is a rotation matrix -> the determinant is 1 and you have 9 equations. Solve these with any of the usual algorithms for solving equation systems and you have the transformation matrix. Getting the axis and angle from that is easy via google: http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToAngle/

#### Second method

Naming your points 0, 1, 2, 3 a, b, c, d respectively, you can get the z coordinates of the vectors between them (e.g. `b-a`) with this idea:

[image]

you will still have to sort out if `b3-a3` is positive, though. One way to do that is to use the centermost point as b (calculate distance from the center for all points, use the one with the minimal distance). Then you know for sure that `b3-a3` is positive (if z is positive towards you).

Now assume that `a` is (0,0,0) in your transformed space and you can calculate all the point positions by adding the appropriate vectors to that.

To get the rotation you use the fact that you know where `b-a` did point in your origin space (e.g. (1,0,0)). You get the rotation angle via dot product of `b-a` and `(1,0,0)` and the rotation axis via cross product between those vectors.

Comment: the first method is essentially the RxRyRz matrix but instead you don't use the cos angles I believe if I am not wrong. But my question is the ninth equation from the determinant with t3,1 t3,2 t3,3 will be a linear equation right? how can you solve that?

Comment: You can find the determinant formula [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#3.C2.A0.C3.97.C2.A03_matrices). For solving the equation system, you could implement [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) or the proper standard algorithm [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition). The complexity of these algorithms is the reason why I proposed a second method.